# SQL join three tables (one is relational table)

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Need some help with a query.. I have three tables.

```
Source
id      name
1       Other
2       Website
3       Wikipedia

Person
id      name
1       Tom
2       Lewis
3       Gary

person_source
person_sources_id  source_id
1                   2
1                   3
3                   3
```

I want to build a query that displays a person and a column for each source - displaying the name of the source if it exists in the relationship and a null if it doesnt:

```
output (for Tom)
-name-
null
Website
Wikipedia
```

I have the following query, but it gives me the sources attached to the contact, without the nulls..

```
    rs2 = s2.executeQuery("select distinct source.name "+
                        "from person left join person_source "+
                        "on person_source.person_sources_id = "+rs.getLong("id")+" join source "+
                        "on source.id = person_source.source_id");
```

My code's current output for Tom:

```
Output (for Tom)
-name-
Website
Wikipedia
```

Thanks

Comment: 1) What are the column names of the output? 2) Do you only have those 3 sources?

Comment: Hi Mosty - The code I have currently takes that result set and adds each source from the result set and appends a comma (to output to CSV). I've leveled this for explanation purposes (I really have about 110,000 people and 20 sources). Outputted column name for my query is "name"

Comment: Is it correct that you are looking for a query that will output dynamic columns, in the case any more Sources are added?

Comment: THanks for responses. I've tried the query I've attached in my question. The results are that I would see Gary (id:1) and just Wikipedia in the column. I want to see, for Gary, in a single column null null Wikipedia.

This is not necessarily dynamic - My code is per call and pulls the most recent Sources list. So it's just a matter of displaying all sources for a single person, either null or the name.

Comment: in that case you probably want an **xml group function** - what RDBMS do you use (Oracle and newest DB2 support these as far as i know)

Comment: Using MySQL and JDBC, with Hibernate overlay. Updated my example - Thanks deathApril.

Comment: oh.. i see in your update that you accept multiple rows but one column, it's much more clear what you want now ;)

Comment: Doesn't `TOM` have both: `Wikipedia` and `Website`?

Comment: Yeah - it wasn't very clear the first time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you already know the person id, you don't need to join `person` table

```
select case when person_source.id is not null
            then source.name
       end "name"
from source
left join person_source
  on source.id = person_source.source_id
  and person_source.person_sources_id = :id
order by source.id
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, this answers your **original** question. I'm not sure of what you're looking for now.

```
select p.name,
  max(if(s.id = 1, s.name, null)) Other,
  max(if(s.id = 2, s.name, null)) Website,
  max(if(s.id = 3, s.name, null)) Wikipedia
from source s
left join person_source ps on s.id = ps.source_id
right join person p on p.id = ps.person_sources_id
group by p.name
order by p.id
```

Result:

```
+-------+-------+---------+-----------+
| NAME  | OTHER | WEBSITE | WIKIPEDIA |
+-------+-------+---------+-----------+
| Tom   |       | Website | Wikipedia |
| Lewis |       |         |           |
| Gary  |       |         | Wikipedia |
+-------+-------+---------+-----------+
```

You can replace `s.id = 1` with `s.name = 'Other'` but that would be less performant.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for group_concat():

```
select person.name as person,  group_concat(source.name) as source_list
 from person
 left join person_source as ps on ( ps.person_source_id=person.id) 
 left join source on source.id = ps.source_id 
 group by person.id
```

This is for mysql, check you respective DBMS for group_concat()